# Angular2 animation '* => void' transition not activating with *ngFor Component item

Tags: angular, angular2-animation

Plunker example
https://plnkr.co/edit/uUs4U63mEItIRvL4nL7s?p=preview

I have a `ul` of `li` notifications that slide in when added. I'd like them to slide out when they're deleted but the `transition('* => void')` doesn't seem to take effect and they just disappear instead of sliding back out. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

**Edit**
Here's an expanded plunker example showing it working with a local list but not when using a component to build the list.

https://plnkr.co/edit/8WZGZu3tuSVBrzUZxBwE?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've handled this case acquiring animations outside a component and defining components tag css with "display: block"

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/E5JYxsGaFsWd22zCVLux?p=preview) is working example. The key thought was

```
notification {display: block;}
```